# Why pushAndRemoveUntil does not remove the same route?

Tags: flutter

For example, current app's route is `AllMessagesView()` (and let it be the first route in the app).
What I want is when I go to the next route all the previous should be deleted. But if I go to the same route, like this

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(); // closes a drawer
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllMessagesView()),
    ModalRoute.withName('/'),
);
```

and then press android's `back` button then it shows me the same route. And if I press `back` button one more time then it close the app.

So why the `pushAndRemoveUntil` does not remove the same route in this case?

Comment: So what is it supposed to do when the back button is pressed while on AllMessageView() page?

Comment: @Davis it should close the app because there should not be any routes except the only AllMessageView() page

Comment: And next time the user clicks on the app I suppose it AllMessageView() page is to be loaded?

Comment: @Davis it's just a sample to show how the code works

Comment: Wrap your button with WillPopScope(); then in it's onWillPop:(){} function do the close drawer then  SystemNavigator.pop();

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you can close or exit the app by doing these modifications right below your code:

```
 Navigator.of(context).pop(); // closes a drawer
  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllMessagesView()),
    ModalRoute.withName('/'),
  );

// Now try to close the app with this:
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    SystemNavigator.pop();
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    exit(0);
  }
```